# Text not sharp in Cocos2d js

Tags: html, cocos2d-js

Is that font issue resolved in Cocos2d js? I am still getting the issue, text is not clear (LabelTTF). I have changed many fonts and also tried different resolution ratio. But no luck so far.

Plz Help!

Comment: Can you please elaborate the issue?

Comment: Text not clear or Labelttf font is not clear. When I switched to Canvas mode then it looks better than Webgl mode